# Prove or Disprove the following: If $K$ is a maximal subgroup that is normal, in $G$ then $G \cong K \times_{\theta}H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think the statement is untrue. And I'm thinking that it can be disproved using a counterexample with the quaternion group and its maximal subgroups $\{1, -1, i, -i\}$, which are obviously normal. But I'm not sure how to actually disprove it.

Comment: A simpler approach: think of the direct product as producing a group which is (at least) "2-dimensional". Now try to find a "1-dimensional" group with a proper maximal normal subgroup . . .

Comment: @user28111: You should post your comment as an answer, it is a nice solution.

Comment: Please try and have the full question in the body of your question, not just in the title.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is exactly the question...

Answer (score 3):

If you mean

> If $K$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ that is normal, is it true that $G$ is a semidirect product by $K$ by a subgroup $H$?

the simplest counterexample is the cyclic group $G$ of order $4$, with $K$ being the *unique* subgroup of order $2$. In fact, if there is such an $H$, then  $\lvert H \rvert = \lvert G / K \rvert = 2$, but there is no subgroup $H$ of order $2$ other than $K$.

The quaternion group $G$ of order $8$ also works, with $K = \{1, -1, i, -i \}$. Here, too, if there is an $H$ such that $G$ is the semidirect product of $K$ by $H$, then $\lvert H \rvert = \lvert G / K \rvert = 2$, but $\{1, -1 \} \le K$ is the only subgroup of order $2$ of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \geq 5$, $\mathfrak{A}_n$ is the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $[\mathfrak{S}_n: \mathfrak{A}_n]=2$.

**Edit:** I supposed the question was about direct product.

Comment: ... and $G = \mathfrak{S}_{n}$ is the semidirect product of $K = \mathfrak{A}_{n}$ by $H = \langle (12) \rangle$.